# wxTextEntryDialog translation of OK and Cancel

Tags: c++, visual-c++, translation, wxwidgets

I have my application with all the translations working perfectly except the 'OK' and 'Cancel' contained in the wxTextEntryDialog dialog. **How can I get these to translate properly?** Even the wxMessageBox is working fine when using OK and Cancel but wxTextEntryDialog doesn't just seem to translate to any other language.

I have used the following snippets for the languages assignment within my code:

```
wxLocale m_locale; // locale we'll be using (this is defined in the header file of my app)
// Within the source
lang = wxLANGUAGE_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED; // for e.g. could be any language

m_locale.Init(lang);
    // normally this wouldn't be necessary as the catalog files would be found in the default locations, but when the program is not installed the
    // catalogs are in the build directory where we wouldn't find them by default
    wxLocale::AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix(wxT(LanguagePath));// add path of install
    // Initialize the catalogs we'll be using
 m_locale.AddCatalog(_("messages"));   // .mo file generated by my application language specific .mo file
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @VZ. for the insight. Your approach helped me debug my application better i.e. I was able to see that the `Init()` did not succeed by checking the return value. With this I was able to investigate further. Also, the `wxstd.mo`is just the default .po generated .mo (not translated so why would I require this?)

Solution: I had to add the wxWidgets translation files i.e. the .mo generated catalog files from the .po files contained in the `<wxdir>/locale/`. I had to copy them to the same directories as my `messages.mo`. Hence, the working code looks like this for Simplified chinese.

```
wxLocale m_locale; // locale we'll be using (this is defined in the header file of my app)
// Within the source
lang = wxLANGUAGE_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED; // for e.g. could be any language

wxLocale::AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix(wxT(LanguagePath));// add path of install

m_locale.Init(lang, wxLOCALE_CONV_ENCODING);

m_locale.AddCatalog(wxT("zh_CN"));  // This is the .mo file I generated from the wxWidgets .po files
    // Initialize the catalogs we'll be using
 m_locale.AddCatalog(_("messages"));   // .mo file generated by my application language specific .mo file
```

I did not include the checks for a purpose because I want the application to run in english even if the language is not supported but I did use it for debugging

Answer (score 1):

Does your call to `Init()` succeed? You should really check for its return value, it's possible that it doesn't find `wxstd.mo`, which contains translations for all the messages used inside wxWidgets, because you call it before setting the lookup path. You need to

1. Ensure that `wxstd.mo` is available in your catalog path.
2. Call `Init()` after setting this path.
3. Check its return value.